# How to mount Docker Volume to a specific directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having the below Docker Compose file in which I am making a volume and then mount all the volume data to my specified directory.

Here is the below code of docker compose file

```
version: '3'

volumes: 
  test:
    driver: local
    driver_opts: 
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: 'D:\test'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - test:/data/db
  
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    volumes:
      - test:/etc/mongo-express
```

But when I run the docker compose I get the following error:

```
D:\Docker-compose>docker-compose -f mongo.yaml up -d
[+] Running 19/19
 ✔ mongo-express 7 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                        18.5s
   ✔ b0e1773ee89e Download complete                                                                                0.0s
   ✔ 0dc151cc3eb8 Download complete                                                                               14.0s
   ✔ 9398808236ff Download complete                                                                                1.9s
   ✔ 1de49a94a524 Download complete                                                                                9.3s
   ✔ ee8c69d204ca Download complete                                                                                0.6s
   ✔ 844e0ac2d780 Download complete                                                                                0.0s
   ✔ 81bee2a0ce57 Download complete                                                                                0.0s
 ✔ mongodb 10 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                          34.9s
   ✔ e062d62b861e Download complete                                                                                0.0s
   ✔ 54a7480baa9d Download complete                                                                                0.0s
   ✔ 43f89b94cd7d Download complete                                                                               14.3s
   ✔ 7f9301fbd7df Download complete                                                                                1.8s
   ✔ 40d046ff8fd3 Download complete                                                                                0.0s
   ✔ 5e4470f2e90f Download complete                                                                                0.4s
   ✔ 74c3fb6d33e0 Download complete                                                                               30.3s
   ✔ 72919e34fde8 Download complete                                                                                0.0s
   ✔ adfd395e3ac5 Download complete                                                                                0.0s
   ✔ 021b676f1558 Download complete                                                                                0.0s
[+] Running 2/4
 ✔ Network docker-compose_default            Created                                                               0.1s
 ✔ Volume "docker-compose_test"              Created                                                               0.0s
 - Container docker-compose-mongo-express-1  Starting                                                             10.3s
 - Container docker-compose-mongodb-1        Starting                                                             10.3s
Error response from daemon: mounting volume docker-compose_test for container da061e8124ac646ea67d4d2bd563db7836a2ddab3a7e44c6e72415e08ff7bff2: mount: /var/lib/containers/storage/volumes/docker-compose_test/_data: special device D:\test does not exist.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

When I checked for docker volume inspect, it is being mounted on the drive:

```
volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     693a25c1c5ba909f6f56ad27587ddd7bb9ebf0220ab54f9c25dc86bd8acedd3c
local     a166c931596773410b2db1cc6e6e19d45dd0ae7e43de939fd5ace793e161aff3
local     buildx_buildkit_default_state
local     docker-compose_test

D:\Docker-compose>docker inspect docker-compose_test
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2023-11-27T19:55:06+05:30",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "docker-compose",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.17.3",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "test"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/containers/storage/volumes/docker-compose_test/_data",
        "Name": "docker-compose_test",
        "Options": {
            "device": "D:\\test",
            "o": "bind",
            "type": "none"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

How to store all the volume data in my specified directory?

Comment: I'd use a Docker [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) for this setup; I wouldn't usually try to create a named volume but attach it to a specific host directory.  That is also more likely to be able to handle the Windows-style paths.